# How I can use 4 different http_methods in the same lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have this function with which I intend to handle instances of ec2, with get I list all the instances in the region, post to create a new instance, put to modify one and delete to delete one instance, I'm using Python 3.9 lambda and serverless

```
import json
import boto3

def ec2_crud(event, context):
    http_method = event['httpMethod']
    try:
        # Crear una conexión con EC2 usando la región en la que se encuentra la función Lambda
        region = context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[3]
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)

        if http_method == 'GET':
            # Obtener todas las instancias de EC2 en la región
            instances = ec2.instances.all()

            instance_list = []
            for instance in instances:
                instance_info = {
                    'InstanceId': instance.id,
                    'InstanceType': instance.instance_type,
                    'State': instance.state['Name']
                }
                instance_list.append(instance_info)

            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps(instance_list)
            }
        elif http_method == 'POST':
      
            try:
               
                request_data = json.loads(event['body'])
                instance_name = request_data['name']
                instance_size = request_data['size']
                instance_keys = request_data['keys']

                ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
                new_instance = ec2_client.run_instances(
                    ImageId='ami-03f65b8614a860c29',  # Reemplaza con la AMI que desees usar
                    InstanceType=instance_size,
                    KeyName=instance_keys,
                    MinCount=1,
                    MaxCount=1
                )['Instances'][0]

                ec2_client.create_tags(Resources=[new_instance['InstanceId']], Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': instance_name}])

                return {
                    'statusCode': 200,
                    'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Nueva instancia creada con éxito.', 'InstanceId': new_instance['InstanceId']})
                }
            except Exception as e:
                return {
                    'statusCode': 500,
                    'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
                }
        elif http_method == 'PUT':
            # Implementar la lógica para actualizar una instancia de EC2
            instance_id = event['pathParameters']['instance_id']
            instance_size = json.loads(event['body'])['size']
            instance_name = json.loads(event['body'])['name']

            # Crear una conexión con el servicio EC2
            ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

            try:
                # Actualizar el tamaño y el nombre de la instancia
                ec2_client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=instance_id, Attribute='instanceType', Value=instance_size)
                ec2_client.create_tags(Resources=[instance_id], Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': instance_name}])

                return {
                    'statusCode': 200,
                    'body': json.dumps({'message': f'Instancia {instance_id} actualizada con éxito.'})
                }

            except Exception as e:
                return {
                    'statusCode': 500,
                    'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
                }
        elif http_method == 'DELETE':
            # Implementar la lógica para eliminar una instancia de EC2
            instance_id = event['pathParameters']['instance_id']

            # Crear una conexión con el servicio EC2
            ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

            try:
                # Eliminar la instancia
                ec2_client.terminate_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])

                return {
                    'statusCode': 200,
                    'body': json.dumps({'message': f'Instancia {instance_id} eliminada con éxito.'})
                }

            except Exception as e:
                return {
                    'statusCode': 500,
                    'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
                }
        else:
            return {
                'statusCode': 400,
                'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Método HTTP inválido.'})
            }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
        }
```

When I test get and post block with curl works well and runs the task but when I try it with put and delete, I get this error:

> Missing Authentication Token

and I don't know why this happens.

I try it to modify and delete ec2 instances

Comment: Could you share your serverless.yml for that ec2_crud function please?

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Is an IAM Role assigned to the AWS Lambda function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is my serverless code `service: my-ec2-crud

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.9
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2

functions:
  ec2_crud:
    handler: handler.ec2_crud
    events:
      - http:
          path: instance
          method: GET
      - http:
          path: instance
          method: POST
      - http:
          path: instance
          method: PUT
      - http:
          path: instance
          method: DELETE`

Comment: The problem is that I can list my instances with get and create  a new one with post, but when I want to modify the atributtes of the instances with PUT appears the messages "Mising autentication token" and the same ocurrs when I try it to delete an instance, with DELETE method

Answer (score 1):

We'd need to see your `serverless.yml` file to check HTTP option configuration.

Typically, you'll see `missing authentication token` when the route exists but the HTTP method is not valid for that route.

You'll likely want to set `method: ANY`, like this example:

```yaml
functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /my-path
          method: ANY
```

If you also wanted any path from that API Gateway instance to route to your function, you can use the `proxy` configuration:

```yaml
functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: ANY {proxy+}
          method: ANY
```